# PHP - How to debug empty response

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm starting to learn PHP and ran into something that I don't know how to debug...

I have two tables in my db, with following structures

`wp_ad_management`:

```
| id | template_id | date_from | date_to | img_url | ad_url | created_at |
```

and `wp_ad_templates`:

```
| id | name | proportions |
```

Here is my PHP to get data from them:

```
switch ($_GET['action']) {
  case 'all_ads':
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `wp_ad_management`");
    break;
  case 'all_templates':
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `wp_ad_templates`");
}

$data = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
  array_push($data, $row);
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

`https://trevim.online/anuncios/php/get.php?action=all_ads` everything is returned as expected 
`https://trevim.online/anuncios/php/get.php?action=all_templates` returns 200 but says no response data is available for this request.

I'm stuck on this for hours, reviewing all the code to try to understand what the difference is between one and the other! Please tell me how can one go about debugging this? There's no errors, nothing, just an empty response, when in fact I know that there are 6 entries in that templates table, which are returned if I run the same SQL directly in PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: Try Using mysqli_fetch_assoc instead of mysqli_fetch_object...
You can see var_dump($row) to debug

Comment: @sathish1409 What is the difference?

Comment: @Dharman mysqli_fetch_object returns Object where it is not an array. mysqli_fetch_assoc returns associative array

Comment: @sathish1409 No, I meant in this situation. Why are you recommending it?

Comment: You need to check if you have any data at all in `wp_ad_templates`

Comment: I am closing this question with the closest related duplicate. It will give you some powerful debugging tools, that would help you in case of a real problem

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use `mysqli_fetch_array` to fetch a result row as an associative array.

```
switch ($_GET['action']) {
  case 'all_ads':
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `wp_ad_management`");
    break;
  case 'all_templates':
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `wp_ad_templates`");
}
$data = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  array_push($data, $row);
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it! Could you please elaborate a bit on why it wasn't working and how to debug in these cases?

Comment: In mysqli you can use `fetch_all` instead of this loop

Comment: @HenriqueSaias just to make it clear: there is **abolutely no difference** which means it worked by *accident*. Not to mention this answer says absolutely nothing on how to debug.